How do i fix this Boost build error from vcpkg
boost fails to build after being downloaded
i tried redoing it reinstalling vcpkg and i expected it to build boost and for it to finish but it fails to build every boost library
Logs:
PS C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\vcpkg\vcpkg> ./vcpkg install boost:x64-windows
Computing installation plan...
The following packages will be built and installed:
boost:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-asio:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-assign:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-beast:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-bimap:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-callable-traits:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-cobalt:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-compat:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-compatibility:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-compute:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-context:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-contract:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-convert:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-coroutine:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-coroutine2:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-crc:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-dll:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-dynamic-bitset:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-fiber:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-flyweight:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-foreach:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-format:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-geometry:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-gil:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-graph:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-hana:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-heap:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-histogram:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-hof:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-icl:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-interprocess:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-iostreams[bzip2,core,lzma,zlib,zstd]:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-json:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-lambda:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-lambda2:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-leaf:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-local-function:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-locale:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-lockfree:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-log:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-math:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-metaparse:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-msm:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-multi-array:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-multi-index:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-multiprecision:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-mysql:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-nowide:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-odeint:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-outcome:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-parameter-python:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-pfr:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-poly-collection:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-polygon:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-process:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-property-map:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-property-tree:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-ptr-container:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-python[core,python3]:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-qvm:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-random:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-rational:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-redis:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-safe-numerics:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-scope-exit:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-signals2:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-sort:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-stacktrace:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-statechart:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-static-string:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-stl-interfaces:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-test:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-timer:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-tti:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-type-erasure:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-units:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-url:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-uuid:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-vmd:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-wave:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-xpressive:x64-windows@1.84.0
boost-yap:x64-windows@1.84.0
bzip2[core,tool]:x64-windows@1.0.8#5
expat:x64-windows@2.6.2
libffi:x64-windows@3.4.6
liblzma:x64-windows@5.4.4
openssl:x64-windows@3.3.0
pkgconf:x64-windows@2.2.0
python3:x64-windows@3.11.8#1
sqlite3[core,json1]:x64-windows@3.45.3
vcpkg-cmake-config:x64-windows@2022-02-06#1
vcpkg-msbuild:x64-windows@2023-08-08
vcpkg-pkgconfig-get-modules:x64-windows@2023-09-06
vcpkg-tool-meson:x64-windows@1.3.2#2
zlib:x64-windows@1.3.1
zstd:x64-windows@1.5.6
Additional packages (*) will be modified to complete this operation.
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-windows...
Compiler found: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.39.33519/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
Restored 0 package(s) from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\vcpkg\archives in 3.8 ms. Use --debug to see more details.
Installing 1/96 boost-context:x64-windows@1.84.0...
Building boost-context:x64-windows@1.84.0...
-- Using cached boostorg-context-boost-1.84.0.tar.gz.
-- Cleaning sources at C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/vcpkg/vcpkg/buildtrees/boost-context/src/ost-1.84.0-b29e9a2161.clean. Use --editable to skip cleaning for the packages you specify.
-- Extracting source C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/vcpkg/vcpkg/downloads/boostorg-context-boost-1.84.0.tar.gz
-- Using source at C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/vcpkg/vcpkg/buildtrees/boost-context/src/ost-1.84.0-b29e9a2161.clean
-- Including C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/vcpkg/vcpkg/buildtrees/boost-context/vcpkg-b2-options.cmake
-- Found external ninja('1.11.0').
-- Getting CMake variables for x64-windows
-- Configuring x64-windows
-- Building x64-windows-dbg
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_build_process.cmake:134 (message):
Command failed: C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/vcpkg/vcpkg/downloads/tools/cmake-3.29.0-windows/cmake-3.29.0-windows-i386/bin/cmake.exe --build . --config Debug --target install -- -v -j9
Working Directory: C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/vcpkg/vcpkg/buildtrees/boost-context/x64-windows-dbg
See logs for more information:
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\vcpkg\vcpkg\buildtrees\boost-context\install-x64-windows-dbg-out.log
Call Stack (most recent call first):
installed/x64-windows/share/vcpkg-cmake/vcpkg_cmake_build.cmake:74 (vcpkg_execute_build_process)
installed/x64-windows/share/vcpkg-cmake/vcpkg_cmake_install.cmake:16 (vcpkg_cmake_build)
installed/x64-windows/share/boost-build/boost-modular-build.cmake:139 (vcpkg_cmake_install)
ports/boost-context/portfile.cmake:22 (boost_modular_build)
scripts/ports.cmake:175 (include)
error: building boost-context:x64-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED
Elapsed time to handle boost-context:x64-windows: 8.3 s

FIXED it was a windows defender issue
